Shapely examples in the documentation not working
I am looking at the shapely documentation for transform with the following examples:
>>> from shapely import Point
>>> from shapely.ops import transform
>>> transform(Point(0, 0), lambda x:x + 1)
<POINT (1 1)>

However, when I try it, it does this:
>>>transform(Point(0, 0), lambda x: x + 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxxx.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxsite-packages\shapely\ops.py", line 264, in transform
    if geom.is_empty:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_empty'

What am I missing?

The AttributeError is legit because you're using a different function.
You want shapely.transform(...)
instead of shapely.ops.transform(...) :
from shapely import Point, transform

transform(Point(0, 0), lambda x: x + 1).wkt # 'POINT (1 1)'
NB: ops.transform will be deprecated soon in favor of transform_resize (see GH1902).

When you use a lambda function, you should handle both x and y coordinates. Also the correct order of parameters for transform is a function first, which is transform(lambda x, y: (x + 1, y + 1),Point(0, 0)) 
